# On the difference in pronunciation between "dessert" and "desert"

Tags: pronunciation

Is it true if I would say that the difference between **dessert** and **desert** is in the [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) (grammar), it means that in the word 'dessert' the stress is on the *second part* of the word (des**sert**) while in the word 'desert' the stress is on the *first part* (**de**sert)?

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: I don't know hot to find such information there.  they are not talking about the place of the stress in the word (first part and second part). I'm trying to understand how to explain verbaly the difference betweent these two words.  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dessert

Comment: The mark ˈ goes before the stressed syllable in Cambridge's transcription. You can see that "dessert" is stressed on the second syllable, while "[desert](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/desert)" is stressed on the first syllable when it is a noun, and on the second syllable when it is a verb.

Comment: @sumelic But when *desert* (noun) is a derivative of *deserve* it is stressed on the ultimate.

Comment: @StoneyB: right, although I've never heard singular "deˈsert" used in modern English, only the plural "deˈserts".

Comment: Also, the verb *desert* meaning *abandon* has the same pronunciation and stress as the noun *dessert*, at least in American English. (Or maybe the first vowel in the verb is a little less of a schwa, but it's a very subtle difference if it's there.)

Comment: @StoneyB You've just taught me something there. I don't think I'd ever seen the phrase "just deserts" written down so had always just assumed it was "just desserts" because of the pronunciation.

Comment: In BrE: desert /ˈdɛzət/, dessert /dɪˈzɜːt/. Can a BrE speaker confirm this?

Comment: @Ustanak correct, so long as "desert" is referring to a dry, barren land. All other meanings of "desert" are pronounced like "dessert".

Comment: @Industrious Are you asking about the facts ("Which syllables are stressed in *desert* and *dessert*?") or are you asking whether your *explanation* gets the idea across correctly?

Comment: About the explanation.  And I found that it's not correct using **'part'** in this context. It should be **syllable**.

Comment: I think everyone who closed your question misunderstood it because of the word *true*.  Anyway, yes, you should say the first or second *syllable* :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Dessert*, meaning something sweet usually consumed at the end of a meal, has stress on the second syllable.

*Desert*, meaning a barren area with sand and lacking water, has stress on the first syllable.

*Desert*, the verb meaning to abandon, is pronounced like *dessert*.

Answer (score 2):

I speak with an American accent.

LawrenceC is correct that the verb "desert" is pronounced like the noun "dessert", and not like the geographical noun "desert".

When I pronounce these words, the difference in the stress causes me to use a different vowel sound for the first syllable.  The geographical noun "desert" has a short "e" sound (like in the abbreviation "rez" for "resolution", or the word "says").  The noun "dessert" has a schwa sound.